# background-image html5

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my exercise. I'm trying to put 3 images in background-image, and there goes 3 urls. Problem is the 3rd isn't shown. (Sorry for any mistakes in language. )
 This looks like :
http://scr.hu/9ygf/660ur
 Should like :
http://scr.hu/9ygf/va1or

Code :
    HTML :

```
<ul id="Nav">    
  <li>About</li>    
  <li>Contact</li>    
  <li>Help</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#Nav  {
    font-size:50px;
    color:blanchedalmond;
    clear:both;
    font-family: inherit;
    background-size: auto;
    background-image: url('MenuLeft.jpg'), url('Menu.jpg'), url('MenuRight.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: left, center,right;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code with question as well..

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ;)

Comment: Haha :P Thanks and welcome too ;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change order of images, result should be:

```
#Nav  {
  font-size:50px;
  color:blanchedalmond;
  clear:both;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-size: auto;
  background-image: url('MenuLeft.jpg'), url('MenuRight.jpg'), url('Menu.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: left, right, center;
}
```

Comment: No problem :) please mark as resolved and upvote. Thanks:)